# Mongoose best practices

Tags: mongoose

I have a bit of a stupid question, namely, is it better to assign the value returned by awaiting Module.save() or just use the original variable that has been used to find the record ? Here is what i mean:

```
export const update = async (id, payload) => {
    const a = await AwesomeModel.findById(productId);
    // do stuff to it . . . 
    const updated = await a.save();
    return formatData(updated);
};
```

or is it the same as:

```
export const update = async (id, payload) => {
        const a = await AwesomeModel.findById(productId);
        // do stuff to it . . . 
        await a.save();
        return formatData(a);
};
```

What's the difference, if any ? Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference here is that you're storing stuff twice. The result you're returning will be the same minus the extra variable you've got in the 1st snippet.

Comment: So, basically, never do it like in the first snippet. Got it, thanks! although I still don't understand why save() returns the promised document when in all cases we have access to it without it returning it. I guess that is what confused me... coming from .net, I am expect SaveChanges to return nothing... and since this works a bit different I was wondering why... Cheers!